# Filtering with multiple criteria using OR in Console.app

Tags: console

It seems that using multiple criteria within search in Console implies an **AND** operator. So if I add a **TagA** and a **TagB** filters, it will find only messages that contains both **TagA** and **TagB** together.

Is it possible to filter using **OR**? That is, that the results will show messages with *either* 'TagA' or 'TagB'?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the filtering criteria work with **OR** operator when they use the ***same*** property shortcut (e.g. `any:` for Any, `p:` for Process, `m:` for Message, `t:` for Message Type).
They work with **AND** operator when they are using ***different*** property shortcuts. At least in macOS 12 Mojave.

Examples:
`t:error` `t:fault` - The default saved search "Errors and Faults" searches for Errors **OR** Faults.
`m:roam` `p:wifi` - Shows messages containing "roam" **AND** in process containing "wifi".

Note: a trick how to search for message containing two phrases is using `m:` **AND** `any:` instead of `m:` **OR** `m:`, for example `any:transitioning` `message:operation`.

You can also search for a phrase containing spaces, e.g. `m:transitioning from state`.